# Getting error "Failed reading APM server info" while connecting to ElasticAPM

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, elastic-apm

I have a .net project. I am trying to add Elastic APM Configuration in it. Below are the configurations I have added:

Program.cs:

```cs
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).UseAllElasticApm().Build().Run();
```

Startup.cs:

```cs
app.UseElasticApm(Config); (Config is of type IConfiguration)
```

I have added the spans in my controller as below:

```cs
[HttpGet("filterValues")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetReportFilterTenant()
{
    var span = _tracer.CurrentTransaction?.StartSpan("predictive-reporting", "ControllerA", "GetFilter","Getting Filter");

    try
    {
        var filterValues = _dataAccess.GetFilters();
        return Ok(filterValues);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        span?.CaptureException(e);
        Console.WriteLine(e);

    }
    finally
    {
        span?.End();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have added the below nuget package in my csproj:

```xml
 <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll" Version="1.22.0" />
```

But, the APM service is not coming up and I am not able to see the logs as well. Also, I am getting the exception below:

```
Elastic.Apm[0]
      {PayloadSenderV2} Failed sending events. Following events were not transferred successfully to the server (http://apm-server.cie-elastic.svc.cluster.loc
al:8200/):
          Error{Id: 0d86aaef35318bf5e34edb4aae779001, TraceId: null, ParentId: null, TransactionId: null}
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (apm-server.cie-elastic.svc.cluster.local:8200)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, Cancell
ationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationTo
ken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationTo
ken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, Cancell
ationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean p
reAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts,
 Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Elastic.Apm.Report.PayloadSenderV2.ProcessQueueItems(Object[] queueItems)
dbug: Elastic.Apm[0]
      {HttpDiagnosticListenerCoreImpl} No current transaction, skip creating span for outgoing HTTP request
dbug: Elastic.Apm[0]
      {HttpDiagnosticListenerCoreImpl} ProcessStopEvent called with no active current transaction, url: https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track - skippi
ng event
```

Can I please get help on this? Thanks.